# Letting AsyncTask have a List<NameValuePair> as Parameter

Tags: android, parameters, arraylist, android-asynctask

I want to send data to my server in form of `JSON`. Firstly, It worked well but now I had to change the class to use `AsyncTask` to do some networking operations because I have faced the `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` problem, and the solution is to use `AsyncTask`. However, I encountered a problem that the constructor `UrlEncodedFormEntity(List<NameValuePair>[])` is undefined. So, what should I change in this class?

**My code:**

```
public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<List<NameValuePair>, Void, String> {
private static String registerURL = "http://sit-edu4.sit.kmutt.ac.th/csc498/53270327/Boss/sftrip/index.php/register";
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

protected String doInBackground(List<NameValuePair>... params) {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(registerURL);
    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } else {
            Log.e("Log", "Failed to download result..");
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        if (is != null) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
        } else {
            Log.e("Log", "Something wrong with IS");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    return json;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<NameValuePair, Void, String> {

     protected String doInBackground(NameValuePair... params) {

     }
}
```

The (NameValuePair... params) actually means that the method doInBackground can have a **unspecified number of parameters**, so you can pass for example an array to it.

```
new JSONParser().execute(new NameValuePair[] { .... your namevaluepairs ... });
```

Furthermore, you could consider changing this line:

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
```

to this:

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params[0]));
```

Which will get the first item of the "params" Array of NameValuePair ArrayLists.

Answer (score 0):

You can always pass the ArrayList as a parameter to the constructor and store it as a field inside JSONParser:

```
public JSONParser(List <NameValuePair> list) { this.list = list; }
```

Also add the private field:

```
private ArrayList <NameValuePair> list = null;
```

Now you can manipulate the list anyway you like in the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getHttpResponse(String url, List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(httpClient.getParams(),true);

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity;
        try {
            entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            String res =  EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            return res;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You should also add a brief description to your code.